# ERROR: Unknown or duplicate parameter: NodeVersion in Rails Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create to deploy a Rails app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I'm using EB CLI for that. I'm able to do the "eb init" without a problem, but when I try to create and environment with "eb create" I always get the following:

```
ERROR: "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow. 
ERROR: Unknown or duplicate parameter: NodeVersion  
ERROR: Unknown or duplicate parameter: NodeCommand  
ERROR: Failed to launch environment.
```

I tried without luck to add a NodeVersion and NodeCommand in a file in ".ebextensions". But to be honest I don't know why is requiring Node stuff if I'm deploying a simple Rails app.

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted the application from Elastic Beanstalk and neglected to update my config.

In `config.yml` in `.elasticbeanstalk` check that the application_name exists on Elastic Beanstalk

```
global:
  application_name: my-application
```

My solution was to remove .elasticbeanstalk and simply

```
eb init
```

Otherwise update to an existing application name.